# How to ORDER BY in SQL UNION of JOINED tables not showing ordered columns in result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get the table where two results of joins will be unioned and ordered by several columns. I've found that columns that are ordered have to be mentioned in each select of union. But I don't want ordered columns appear in result. Is it possible? Maybe there are another ways of getting the result that I want.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT coupon_id,
       coupon_name,
       real_price,
       discount_price,
       difference_percent,
       discount_percent,
       payment_price,
       photo,
       company_id,
       company_name
FROM
  (SELECT cpn.id AS coupon_id,
          cpn.name_ru AS coupon_name,
          cpn.real_price,
          cpn.discount_price,
          cpn.difference_percent,
          cpn.discount_percent,
          cpn.payment_price,
          cp.photo,
          com.id company_id,
          com.name_ru AS company_name
   FROM coupon cpn
   LEFT JOIN coupon_photo cp ON cpn.id = cp.coupon_id
   LEFT JOIN company com ON cpn.company_id = com.id
   WHERE cpn.id NOT IN
       (SELECT coupon_id AS id
        FROM transaction
        WHERE Date_add(created_time, interval 10 MINUTE) > Now()
          AND status = 'pending')
     AND cpn.exp_date > Now()
     AND cpn.valid_date > Now()
     AND cpn.available > 0
   UNION SELECT cpn.id AS coupon_id,
                cpn.name_ru AS coupon_name,
                cpn.real_price,
                cpn.discount_price,
                cpn.difference_percent,
                cpn.discount_percent,
                cpn.payment_price,
                cp.photo,
                com.id company_id,
                com.name_ru AS company_name
   FROM coupon cpn
   LEFT JOIN coupon_photo cp ON cpn.id = cp.coupon_id
   LEFT JOIN company com ON cpn.company_id = com.id
   LEFT JOIN transaction trans ON cpn.id = trans.coupon_id
   WHERE cpn.exp_date > Now()
     AND cpn.valid_date > Now()
     AND Date_add(trans.created_time, interval 10 MINUTE) > NOW()
     AND trans.status = 'pending'
     AND (cpn.available - trans.amount) > 0 GROUP  BY cpn.id) results
ORDER BY cpn.advertised DESC,
         cpn.sold DESC,
         cpn.views DESC
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this (simple question!), yourself?

Comment: I've looked through all given questions that are similiar to this one. I tried to order two selects separately but that didn't give the expected result.

Comment: Add the columns you need for ordering to the SELECT clause for each member of the union. This doesn't mean you must also add them to the SELECT clause of the main query; leave **that** unchanged, but add in the subqueries.

Comment: Well, ordering by an invisible column is not useful in most cases. The result look unordered unless you explain.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `results` subquery does not contain the column you are trying to `order by`. You need to add them to both parts of the union. You do not have to add them to your select, but they need to be present in the subquery so you can use them in your `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT coupon_id,
       coupon_name,
       real_price,
       discount_price,
       difference_percent,
       discount_percent,
       payment_price,
       photo,
       company_id,
       company_name
FROM
  (SELECT cpn.id AS coupon_id,
          cpn.name_ru AS coupon_name,
          cpn.real_price,
          cpn.discount_price,
          cpn.difference_percent,
          cpn.discount_percent,
          cpn.payment_price,
          cp.photo,
          cpn.advertised,
          cpn.sold,
          cpn.views,
          com.id company_id,
          com.name_ru AS company_name
   FROM coupon cpn
   LEFT JOIN coupon_photo cp ON cpn.id = cp.coupon_id
   LEFT JOIN company com ON cpn.company_id = com.id
   WHERE cpn.id NOT IN
       (SELECT coupon_id AS id
        FROM transaction
        WHERE Date_add(created_time, interval 10 MINUTE) > Now()
          AND status = 'pending')
     AND cpn.exp_date > Now()
     AND cpn.valid_date > Now()
     AND cpn.available > 0
   UNION SELECT cpn.id AS coupon_id,
                cpn.name_ru AS coupon_name,
                cpn.real_price,
                cpn.discount_price,
                cpn.difference_percent,
                cpn.discount_percent,
                cpn.payment_price,
                cp.photo,
                cpn.advertised,
                cpn.sold,
                cpn.views,
                com.id company_id,
                com.name_ru AS company_name
   FROM coupon cpn
   LEFT JOIN coupon_photo cp ON cpn.id = cp.coupon_id
   LEFT JOIN company com ON cpn.company_id = com.id
   LEFT JOIN transaction trans ON cpn.id = trans.coupon_id
   WHERE cpn.exp_date > Now()
     AND cpn.valid_date > Now()
     AND Date_add(trans.created_time, interval 10 MINUTE) > NOW()
     AND trans.status = 'pending'
     AND (cpn.available - trans.amount) > 0 GROUP  BY cpn.id) results
ORDER BY advertised DESC,
         sold DESC,
         views DESC
```

As Strawberry has pointed out, it is not exactly best practice o use `GROUP BY` when you are not aggregating anything. In this case it can lead to unexpected results as MySQL uses ANY_VALUE(). It returns the value of some row in the GROUP BY group. Which row it returns is indeterminate. That means it's entirely up to the MySQL server.

I assume you were using it to avoid duplicate rows. You should find another de-duplication method.

Furthermore, doing a LEFT JOIN but then filtering the elements on the right side of the JOIN is the same as doing an INNER JOIN. Just make sure this is consistent with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: TO be fair the OP stated that they knew this in there question, so not sure what you actually achieved here

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x...WHERE x </>/=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: ...and, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: @RiggsFolly  OP was worried that he has to display the columns, he does not have to select the columns  but the columns need to be present in the table(in our case the subquery) so he can order by them

Comment: SO add that useful information to the Answer and it will make the answer worth so much more to the OP and anyone else that comes to read your answer

Comment: @Strawberry I did not really pay attention to the query, just the problem. I do agree with you on both accounts.

Comment: Thnx for the answers. You all really helped me. I'm using GROUP BY because coupon_photo contains several elements for one coupon_id

Comment: I thought I should use GROUP BY when tables that are joined may contain several fields that are related to field in base table. Is this wrong?

Comment: So I've removed group by. Now I'm getting two rows of coupon with the same cpn.id. Because it has two photos in cp(coupon_photo) table

Comment: @Bakhrom Great, sounds like you're getting the hang of it.